# How to Get Value Stored in Memory Instead of Memory Object

Tags: python, class, data-structures, methods

I am learning Graphs and have a simple Graph Class with Node and Edge Objects. Each Edge has a Value, Node_From, and Node_To. When I go to print an edge list, however, the Value comes out as the integer I want, but the Node_From and Node_To values come out as the memory object. **How do I get the value stored at that memory object?** Relevant code follows, then output.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.edges = []

class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, value, node_from, node_to):
        self.value = value
        self.node_from = node_from
        self.node_to = node_to

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, nodes=[], edges=[]):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges

    def get_edge_list(self):
        """Don't return a list of edge objects!
        Return a list of triples that looks like this:
        (Edge Value, From Node Value, To Node Value)"""
        triples = []
        for edge in self.edges:
            triples.append((edge.value, edge.node_from, edge.node_to))
        return triples
```

Output of `print(graph.get_edge_list())`:

[(100, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7750>, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7790>), (101, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7750>, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7810>), (102, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7750>, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7890>), (103, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7810>, <graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7890>)]

The `100`, `101`, `102`, etc. are the values that I want and correct, but I also want the values for the node_from and node_to parts of each Edge object, not the memory location for each. How do I turn the `<graph_representation.Node object at 0x7ffbee5f7750>` into whatever value is stored at that memory location? Thanks!

Comment: If you just want `edge.value`, then append *only that* to your list, and refrain from appending the other two things you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies if I was unclear: I want the edge value, the node from, and the node to values all in the tuple. What I don't want is the memory locations.

Comment: I have no idea what values a `Node` object might have, since you didn't show that class.

Comment: You mentioned that you have a Node class. Can you share that?

Comment: @jasonharper node class added, though that class isn't referenced in the method. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, if the field of interest in the `Node` class is called `value`, you want to append `edge.node_from.value` and `edge.node_to.value` to your list.

Comment: @jasonharper that worked! Ah, and that's why you wanted to see the node class: I'm storing a link to the actual node, not its value in the edge list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning @jasonharper's comment into an answer so everyone can easily reference.

The issue was in adding `edge.node_from` and `edge.node_to` to the list. Those are references to node objects, so they return the memory location. We need to add `edge.node_from.value` and `edge.node_to.value` to get the values from those nodes rather than the memory objects. Thus the method is resolved as:

```
def get_edge_list(self):
        """Don't return a list of edge objects!
        Return a list of triples that looks like this:
        (Edge Value, From Node Value, To Node Value)"""
        triples = []
        for edge in self.edges:
            triples.append((edge.value, edge.node_from.value, edge.node_to.value))
        return triples
```

This returns the expected output of:

```
[(100, 1, 2), (101, 1, 3), (102, 1, 4), (103, 3, 4)]
```

Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the default output for an object that hasn't overwritten either the **str**() method or the **repr**() method.

You could get what you want by adding this to your Node class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.edges = []
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

Just keep in mind that this will happen any time you print and there may be times you want to distinguish 2 nodes with the same value apart from each other.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Just tried, but this didn't work: got the same output.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try overwriting the __repr__() method too?

Comment: Yes, that wasn't the problem.